# Minimalize URL redirections (search request)

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

On my wordpress site I have changed my search slug from `?s=some-word` into `/search/some-word` with this part of code:

```php
function change_search_slug() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_search_slug' );
```

Everything is working fine, but I get a redirection 302 from `my-site.com?s=some-word` into `my-site.com/search/some-word`. I am wondering if there is a way to make only one request without the redirection.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: You are explicitly doing a redirect, so the user receives a 302 code with the redirection

Comment: OK, You are right of course. But I am wondering if I use PHP I can make no redirections

Comment: But I am wondering if there is a way to have a search slug like `/search/some-word` and have no redirections